# How do I get the handle of a console application's window

Tags: c#, console, hwnd, window-handles

Can someone tell me how to get the handle of a Windows console application in C#? In a Windows Forms application, I would normally try `this.Handle`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Not sure it works, but you can try that :

```
IntPtr handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle;
```

Comment: For anyone else looking 2-22 years later; yes, this did work (for me).

Comment: this appears to only work if your process started the console.  if you run it from another console, you always get zero.  it looks like you need to use findwindowbycaption in other situations (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/124103)

Comment: This worked for me when debugging in Visual Studio, but when I ran without debugging it didn't. Double clocking the myProgram.exe in bin/Release did work, but `FindWindowByCaption` might be the more robust solution.

Comment: Earlier I always had much respect for this window and I never though I could manipulate it via code but it is a simple window that is not much different than others. The line above **works** and you can also enumerate and find it via WinApi and do all kinds of crazy stuff to it. Just be careful it has a `WndProc` that makes it resize a little differently.

Answer (score 33):

- The aforementioned [`Process.MainWindowHandle` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1277609/648265) [only works for the process that started the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277563/how-do-i-get-the-handle-of-a-console-applications-window/28616832#comment7926605_1277609)
- The [`FindWindowByCaption` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4895594/648265) is inherently unreliable

Here's a robust way to do this:

The related functions from the [Console Win32 API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) are:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool AttachConsole(uint dwProcessId);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true, ExactSpelling=true)]
static extern bool FreeConsole();
```

- For the console the current process is attached to, just `GetConsoleWindow()` is enough
- For the console another process is attached to, attach to it as well with `AttachConsole`, call `GetConsoleWindow`, them immediately detach with `FreeConsole`.

For the extra cautious, register a console event handler before attaching (and unregister it after detaching) as well so you don't accidentally get terminated if a console event happens in the tiny time frame you're attached to the console:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlDelegate HandlerRoutine,
   bool Add);
delegate Boolean ConsoleCtrlDelegate(CtrlTypes CtrlType);
enum CtrlTypes : uint {
    CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
    CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
    CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,  
    CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
    CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
}

bool is_attached=false;    
ConsoleCtrlDelegate ConsoleCtrlDelegateDetach = delegate(CtrlType) {
     if (is_attached = !FreeConsole())
         Trace.Error('FreeConsole on ' + CtrlType + ': ' + new Win32Exception());
     return true;
};
```

---

Making changes to the current process just to read something is rather ugly (when this is a console process, this gets really ugly since it requires a helper process to avoid terminating the current console). Nevertheless, further investigation shows that there's no other way short of injecting into the `csrss` process or the target process.

Console correspondence information is located in and managed by `csrss.exe` (or a multitude of those, one for each session, since Vista), so it can't be retrieved with the likes of `ReadProcessMemory`. All that `csrss` exposes is the [CSRSS LPC API](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/?p=349). There's only one relevant function in the full API list, `SrvGetConsoleWindow`. And it doesn't accept a PID but determines that of the calling party as seen in [an alternative implementation](http://doxygen.reactos.org/d6/dc4/frontendctl_8c_source.html#l00272) or the function's disassembly in `winsrv.dll`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  GetConsoleWindow is the right way to do this; many of the other answers here are just plain goofy.

Comment: This is the correct answer IMHO, unless you want to spend time figuring out why your application doesn't work when you run it from the console as opposed to the IDE. Thanks Ivan.

Comment: Please note that the official MS documentation says that `GetConsoleWindow()` is semi-deprecated and, while it will be supported, it is NOT recommended for new code.

Comment: @PrincessRTFM Reading the MSDN article on `GetConsoleWindow`, that's not actually what they call "deprecation" -- they aren't removing it anytime in the future. They rather suggest to move to using terminal control sequences -- which don't require getting the console's window handle at all. So this fact is not very relevant to the current question.

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr zeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
…

Console.Title = "Test";
…

IntPtr handle = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, Console.Title);
```

Answer (score 9):

I've just solved this problem for myself (unfortunately before seeing [Thomas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1277609/825637) which is much quicker). Well, here's another way for those who are not satisfied with his answer. I'm writing this answer because I want to provide another answer + a better way to design the `Program` class if you're treating your console as a Window. Let's begin with that design:

I've kind of changed the default style of the `Program` class. I've actually made it into a class that has a program in it, and not just one method which represent it and uses other classes for content. (If you don't know what I mean, not important).

The reason I had to do it is because I wanted to write the following event handler:

```
private void CatchUnhandled(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    var exception = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
    MessageBox.Show(this, exception.Message, "Error"); // Check out 1st arg.
}
```

It overloads this method [`MessageBox.Show(IWin32Window, String, String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y3c0fky.aspx).

Because Console doesn't implement [`IWin32Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.iwin32window.aspx), I had to implement it myself, of course, in order to just call `this` in the 1<sup>st</sup> argument.

**Here is the implementation of it and everything else:**

*Note: this code is copy-pasted from my application, you can feel free to change the access modifiers*

`Program` Class Declaration:

```
internal class Program : IWin32Window
{
    ...
}
```

[`IWin32Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.iwin32window.aspx) Implementation:

```
public IntPtr Handle
{
    get { return NativeMethods.GetConsoleWindow(); }
}
```

It uses the following class:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
}
```

Now, the problem is that you can't actually call `this` in `Main`, being a static method, so whatever was in `Main` I've moved to a new method named `Start` and all `Main` is doing is creating a new `Program` and calling `Start`.

```
private static void Main()
{
    new Program().Start();
}

private void Start()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CatchUnhandled;

    throw new Exception();
}
```

The result was, of course, a message-box with my console's window as an owner. 
*Using this method for a message-box, is of course only one application of this method.*

Comment: In short the answer is:    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] internal static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a thing. The console window is not accessible to the application. You MIGHT try to iterate the process list looking for your own process name. The `Process` class IIRC contains a property for the program's main window handle, which *might* be the console window for console applications - which I'm not sure of.

Comment: "iterate the process list looking for your own process name" => not a very efficient approach... you could find it by the PID, or use } ;)

Comment: Whoops - Thomas Levesque's answer is even more elegant. While relying on the same property, he doesn't need to iterate. I forgot that you can access to current process directly...

Comment: @Thomas: Sorry, didn't see your comment before. Of course, iterating is far more inefficient. I didn't remember the GetCurrentProcess() method...

Answer (score 0):

One more version in VB.Net on how to show MessageBox on top of console window

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Friend Module NativeMethods
    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> Friend Function GetConsoleWindow() As IntPtr
    End Function
End Module

NotInheritable Class WndProxy
    Implements IWin32Window
    ReadOnly Property Handle As IntPtr Implements IWin32Window.Handle
    Sub New(_hwnd As IntPtr)
        Handle = _hwnd
    End Sub
End Class

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        ' using MainWindowHandle
        Dim w = New WndProxy(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle)
        MessageBox.Show(w, "Hi")
        ' using GetConsoleWindow api
        Dim s = New WndProxy(NativeMethods.GetConsoleWindow)
        MessageBox.Show(s, "Hi")
    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score -1):

In a console application which streamed diagostics to the console, and for which I wanted to disable mouse input, I tried 
`GetConsoleWindow(), 
Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, and FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, Console.Title)`.
Each of these returned the same non-zero handle, but when I tried to use that handle in SetConsoleMode it threw a "Invalid Handle" exception. Finally I tried `SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), mode | ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS))` with STD_INPUT_HANDLE defined as -10, and it worked. MS's documentation suggests that handles to consoles may be reassigned, and I am not comfortable or happy with this solution, but so far it is the only thing I've found that allows me to disable quick edit mode programmatically. `GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)` returns '3', the other calls return a 7 digit value that varies each time the program is run.